# MVC action doesn't get hit by a jquery ajax call

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following Knockout.js code:

```
this.submitRequest = function () {
           var url = '@Url.Action("GetDetails", "BrowseItems")';

           $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: ko.toJSON(self.searchRequest),
                success: function (data) { }
            });
        };
```

This ajax call is supposed to hit a GetDetails Action inside a BrowseItems Controller and it does work for my partner, but not for me. The exact same code. I even went so far as blast my whole project and reload it from TFS to make sure that there are no code quirks. So, I know that I have the same code as my partner, yet it works for him, but not for me. This seems to me like I have to set some sort of Visual Studio environment setting. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You should check in the development console (IE/Chrome) or Firebug what is the server response for your request, and update your post with the response message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off how are you testing for whether it is getting hit or not? Debugging? because if so that can be a problem as if you are running through IIS and using the IIS pages and debugging through visual studios local server you will never have visual studio detect a bug on IIS. However lets say you simply are clicking run (debug) which it sounds like. The next thing I would check then is your Global.asax file which has your routes setup. If you dont see something like {controller}/{action} that could possibly be causing a problem. A last suggestion is that instead of wrapping the @Url in ' ' wrap it in " ".